# Convert integer to hours mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm storing a duration as a decimal 0.5 for half hour, 2 for two hours, and so on. When doing some calculations with times, I need to have this represented in H:i:s, so 0.5 = 00:30:00.

How should I approach this in Mysql? The application is small and not for public consumption, and so I'm not fussed if the solution is hackish.

My goal is to be able to use it in TIMEADD(my_time, duration). Did I miss something in the manual?

Answer (score 3):

Try this query

```
select 
   id, 
   type, 
   details,
   duration,
   SEC_TO_TIME(duration*60*60) AS durationInTime 
from 
   tbl
```

### **[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fb244/3)**:

```
| ID |     TYPE |             DETAILS | DURATION |                 DURATIONINTIME |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  1 |    Email | admin@sqlfiddle.com |     10.5 | January, 01 1970 10:30:00+0000 |
|  2 |  Twitter |          @sqlfiddle |        5 | January, 01 1970 05:00:00+0000 |
|  3 | blahblah |                 XYZ |      5.5 | January, 01 1970 05:30:00+0000 |
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Try This :-

```
select SEC_TO_TIME(0.5*60*60);
```

Out put:-

```
'00:30:00'
```